# List all sub-folders from file input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/qevorelaga/edit?html,js,console,output) to get list of all files inside folder.
Similarly, is there any way to get list of all sub-folders selected in input tab?

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory="" directory="">
```